# Flutter: Extract a part of Json and Convert to String

Tags: sql, json, flutter

I'm trying to Extract some data from sql Database using Sql_conn package, and I find it hard to convert from:

I/flutter (28173): [{"UserName":"Practica1                     "}]   to just "Practica1" as String.
And also need to use trim to eliminate all spaces.

Here is the code:

```js
Future<bool> checkUserExists(String userInput) async {
  try {
    await SqlConn.connect(
      ip: "192.16****5",
      port: "1433",
      databaseName: "XXXXXXXXX",
      username: "c***",
      password: "As******1",
    );
    var sql = "SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE UserName = '$userInput'";
    var resultSet = await SqlConn.readData(sql);
    print(resultSet);
    return resultSet.isNotEmpty;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
jsonDecode(resultSet)[0]['UserName'].trim()
```